# i want to set my location in google map using android

Tags: android, google-maps

```
MarkerOptions markerOptions = new MarkerOptions().position(position)
            .draggable(true);
@Override
public boolean onMarkerClick(Marker marker) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Log.i("GoogleMapActivity", "onMarkerClick");
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
            "Marker Clicked: " + marker.getTitle(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
            .show();
    return false;
}

@Override
public void onMarkerDrag(Marker arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public void onMarkerDragEnd(Marker marker) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    double lat = marker.getPosition().latitude;
    double lng = marker.getPosition().longitude;
    Toast.makeText(
            getApplicationContext(),
            "Marker " + marker.getTitle() + " dragged from " + fromPosition
                    + " to " + lat + lng, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}

@Override
public void onMarkerDragStart(Marker marker) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    fromPosition = marker.getPosition();
    Log.e(getClass().getSimpleName(), "Drag start at: " + fromPosition);

}
```

in this code its work completed but i want to set pin map center and draggable to map and then to set lat and long

Comment: What is your question actually?

Comment: i want to set in business app's to set location in google map.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code..

```
map = mapView.getMap();
    markerOptions = new MarkerOptions();
    MapsInitializer.initialize(this.getActivity());
    appLocationService = new AppLocationService(getActivity());
    nwLocation = appLocationService.getLocation(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);
    if (nwLocation != null) {
        userlatitude = nwLocation.getLatitude();
        userlongitude = nwLocation.getLongitude();
        MarkerOptions userlocmarker = new MarkerOptions();
        userlocmarker.position(new LatLng(userlatitude, userlongitude));
        userlocmarker.icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.usermarker));
        userlocmarker.title("You are here!");
        userlocmarker.snippet("");
        map.addMarker(userlocmarker);
        MapsInitializer.initialize(this.getActivity());
        CameraUpdate cameraUpdate = CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(new LatLng(userlatitude, userlongitude), 11);
        map.animateCamera(cameraUpdate);
    }
```

Comment: what else do u want to do then?

Comment: ok i have example for it .. like i live in etc city and now i change my city and my home . so i have already set my location in google map now i want to change my location in google map using android.

Comment: using which method, you want to change the location? longtouch? touch?

Comment: MarkerOptions markerOptions = new MarkerOptions().position(position)
            .draggable(true); its set the current location and to implements  OnMarkerDragListener this method to change the location on drag end its default method.